# Spring Boot и Spring Data создать Query динамически

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Нужно на frontend сортировать данные таблицы (ORDER BY). Сейчас запросы в БД (PostgreSQL) идут используя `@Query`аннотации. В таблице 5 столбцов, и не хочется делать много `@Query` для каждого столбца таблице, как динамически создавать запрос в БД, чтобы frontend сам указывал что нужно отсортировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) и передавать в [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) в методы репозитория.

Comment: Получить `List` из `Page` проще всего с помощью метода [getContent()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--). Но при вызове метода с `Sort` должен возвращаться `Iterable`, а не `Page`.

Comment: а фильтр (Like) можно сделать подобным образом?

Comment: Да, [можно](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation): `discontCardRepository.findBySomeFieldLike(sort)`

Comment: а ключ = значение? Чтобы frontend  сам указывал столбцы и значения?

Comment: Ага, забыл, после `sort` вторым параметром значения для `someField` надо указать.

Comment: А возможно ли чтобы пользователь присылал собственно SomeField1 = значение, SomeField2 = значение?

Comment: Возможно. Но когда полей становится много, имя автогенерируемого метода становится длинным и сложным для восприятия. В этом случае лучше вернутся к использованию `@Query`. Что не мешает продолжить использовать `Sort` или `Pageable` первым параметром.

Comment: можно пример? Просто я же не могу создать автогенерируемый метод динамически?

Comment: Не можете, вам придётся точно знать, сколько и каких именно именно параметров примет контроллер от пользователя и передаст в репозиторий. Если это неизвестно, то боюсь, что придётся отказаться от Spring Data и перейти к использованию чего-нибудь типа JPA Criteria API.

Comment: Пользователь может отправить 3 поля максимум, - поле1 = значение, поле2 = значение, поле3 = значение, но может и отправить поле1 = значение, поле3 = значение. Вопрос в том можно ли не писать методы на все случаи а написать что-небудь одно что делало бы LIKE, те получается frontend должен безопасно отправить query на backend

Comment: Для этой цели можно попробовать применить [QBE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example), но мне не доводилось, честно говоря.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой, удобный и гибкий вариант, на мой взгляд, - использовать расширения [QueryDSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) и [Web support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web). Из коробки получаем динамическую фильтрацию, с поддержкой сортировки и пагинации!

Сначала необходимо подключить QueryDSL в проект:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>                                                       
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Затем нужно скомпилировать проект, чтобы создать Q-файлы для сущностей (например, `mvn compile`).

После, создать репо, наследуясь, в том числе, от `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` и, опционально, от QuerydslBinderCustomizer, например:

```
interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<MyEntity> {
}
```

Если в проекте используется [Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/), то можно будет сразу использовать подобные запросы:

```
/myEntities?field1=value1&field2=value2&sort=field2,desc&size=10&page=2
```

Если нужно создать свой контроллер, то делается это, например, так:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myEntities")
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired private MyEntityRepo repo;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = MyEntity.class, bindings = MyEntityRepo.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

        Page<MyEntity> entities = repo.findAll(predicate, pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(entities);
    }
}
```

Для кастоимизации фильтра необходимо использовать метод `customize` `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`а:

```java
public interface MyEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMyEntity> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QMyEntity entity) {

      bindings.excluding( // исключаем не нужные поля из фильтра
          entity.id,
          entity.version,
          // ...
      );

      // реализуем фильтр between по полую field1
      bindings.bind(entity.field1).all((path, value) -> {

          Iterator<? extends Integer> it = value.iterator();
          Integer from = it.next();
          if (value.size() >= 2) {
              Integer to = it.next();
              return path.between(from, to)); // between: если поле field1 указано в строке запроса два раза
          } else {
              return path.goe(from); // greter than: если поле field1 указано один раз
          }
      });

      // фильтр like по полю field2
      bindings.bind(entity.field2).first(StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);        
    }
}
```